# AWS Boto3 Compatibility Issue, How can I install an older version of Boto3?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

I'm trying to deploy my Django project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
The tutorial I am following is suggesting I use Boto3 to link up my S3 Database.

The problem is when I am installing Boto3 i am getting this message in red.

```
awsebcli 3.20.3 requires botocore<1.24.0,>1.23.41, but you have botocore 1.27.7 which is incompatible.
```

So I'm trying to install the older version of Botocore, 1.24.0 or 1.23.41, but after looking at PyPi I can't seem to find it since it just says use pip3 install boto3.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem:
If you already installed boto3 then do these:

1. pip uninstall boto3
2. pip uninstall botocore
3. pip uninstall s3transfer

then do these:

1. pip install botocore==1.23.54
2. pip install boto3==1.20.54

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
pip install boto3==1.21.21

pip install botocore==1.24.21

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this is to use [python virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

The AWS EB CLI is pegged to a very specific version of botocore and they don't update it very often.  As a result, you don't want it to be in the mix for your project dependencies because it will make it hard for you to install other libraries (like modern versions of boto3).

A general setup that you can use is the following:

1. Install awsebcli globally (you only need it for its scripts)
2. Make a virtual environment for your project
3. Install all of your project dependencies in the virtual env; do **not** install awsebcli in the virtual env

If this doesn't work (such as you have other things you need to install globally with conflicting subdependenceis), you should install awsebcli in its own virtual env and have aliases to activate it, but that gets really messy.